# KVM kernel module error

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I just installed qemu and ran

```
qemu-system-i386 -hda ubuntu32 -cdrom ~/Downloads/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso -m 1024 -boot d
```

and got some errors

```
Could not access KVM kernel module: No such file or directory
failed to initialize KVM: No such file or directory
Back to tcg accelerator.
```

Anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am by no means an expert, however from what I know this could happen because either:

a) Your CPU does not support hardware virtualization

b) CPU does support virtualization, but you have not enabled it in BIOS.

Comment: I had the same issue and trying to load the KVM kernel module would give this error: FATAL: Error inserting kvm_intel /lib/modules kernel/arch/x86/kvm/kvm-intel.ko Operation not supported -- your solution worked for me as well. I just had to shutdown and unplug the laptop after changing the BIOS setting to enable virtualization support

Comment: I have the same issue on ubuntu 12.04 server. I even installed `cpu-checker` and ran `kvm-ok` which returned `INFO: /dev/kvm exists` and `KVM acceleration can be used`. Have run kvm in the past on this machine, stumped as to what I've done differently this time.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same error and this worked fine for me !
Try to run this command and then run ur guest .

modprobe kvm-intel

Hope it should work fine !